# Ubuntu says I have two display and cursor flickers

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, flicker

Hello I recently installed Ubuntu 14 on my macbook pro and I'm having an issue with the display settings on it.

My cursor seems to flicker and disappear most of the time. I also noticed I have two monitors that appear in my display settings and I can assure you that I do not have any external monitors connected to my MacBook Pro

so after googling for a bit I see it has to due with some display issue. I noticed that a lot of ways to solve this was to use `xrandr` and disable the extra display that appears.

```
jeanp3rez@Jean-MacBookPro:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2704 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1680x1050      59.9*+
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      59.9  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       59.9  
   1280x854       59.9  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
   848x480        59.7  
   720x480        59.7  
   640x480        59.4  
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS1 connected 1024x768+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x800       60.2 +
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

however, with this method most of the results have been that the extra monitor is a `VGA1` in the `xrandr` in my case my extra monitor is called `LVDS1` and when i disable it my screen goes black and i have to restart my computer. I noticed that when people have this issue they disable the extra monitor but in my case I am unable to do via `xrandr` or maybe I am doing it incorrectly.

I am using a MacBook Pro Early 2011 with a 1680x1050 resolution.

Any ideas on how I can disable that "ghost" monitor and stop the cursor flickering?

I would Post Images however since I am new to this section of Stack Exchange for Ubuntu I can not.